# How to handle multiple groups of radio button in react?

Tags: reactjs

So I'm getting some data from backend which looks something like this

```
{"data":[{"status":1, "title":"Title 1"}, {"status":2, "title":"Title 2"}, {"status":1, "title":"Title 3"}, {"status":3, "title":"Title 4"}]}
```

They are to be mapped into a list where the value of status determines one of 3 radio buttons which I did like below

```
{data.map(d => {
    return (
       <ListGroupItem>
          <Row>
            {d.title}
            <FormGroup>
            <Input
               type="radio"
               name={d.title}
               value="1"
               checked={d.status === 1}
               onChange={this.changeHandler}
             />
             Open
             </FormGroup>
             <FormGroup check inline>
                <Input
                  type="radio"
                  name={d.title}
                  value="2"
                  checked={d.status === 2}
                  onChange={this.changeHandler}
                />
                In-progress
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup check inline>
                 <Input
                    type="radio"
                    name={d.title}
                    value="3"
                    checked={d.status === 3}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                 />
                 Closed
               </FormGroup>
           </Row>
        </ListGroupItem>
   );
})}
```

So my list would look something like

```
Title 1      * open  0 in-progress  0 closed
Title 2      0 open  * in-progress  0 closed
Title 3      * open  0 in-progress  0 closed
Title 4      0 open  0 in-progress  * closed
```

(not the best way to show this)

Now I need this in a form so that when submitted the selected value will updated data in the backend. How would I go about doing that? Also how will I handel the onChange event since right now even if I select a radio button nothing will change.

```
changeHandler = e => {
   //map the data to the proper place
}

submitHandler = e => {
   //submit the data
}
```

P.S. I'm very new to React so this might not be the best way to do this. If there is a better way please let me know.

Comment: You should learn controlled components in react and then you can use state and setState() to control input element. This document may be helpful for you. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: You might want to checkout this cool library called Formik. It provides a clean and easy way to work with forms in React. Link here: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview. Also, as @ZHANGLuyao mentioned, a good understanding of controlled/uncontrolled components would go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is ok, but the change event haven't been handled the right way so the state won't update.

At first, I suppose that this is the shape of the state:

```js
this.state = {
  data: [
    { title: "Title 1", status: 1 },
    { title: "Title 2", status: 2 },
    { title: "Title 3", status: 1 },
    { title: "Title 4", status: 3 }
  ]
};
```

Then the state can be updated as follow (heavily inspired from Redux)

```js
handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    // the map method doesn't mutate the original array, it returns a new one
    data: this.state.data.map(item => {
      // iterate through the array to find the right item to update
      if (item.title !== event.target.name) {
        // not match, so we won't change anything here
        return item;
      } else {
        // match, we return the updated value
        return {
          title: item.title,
          // event.target.value is a string, but the state uses number so we have to convert it
          status: Number(event.target.value)
        };
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Finally, you can send the state when handling the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than one question?
some like this...

```
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className='form-group'>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name='park'
                    value='Ok'
                    onChange={cambioDeEstado}
                />
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name='park'
                    value='No Ok'
                    onChange={cambioDeEstado}
                />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group'>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name='house'
                    value='Ok'
                    onChange={cambioDeEstado}
                />
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name='house'
                    value='No Ok'
                    onChange={cambioDeEstado}
                />
            </div>

            <button type='submit'>next..</button>
        </form>
```