# Changing components in a view in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a hard time understanding how Routes work in React. Right now I have my App.js with my routes for different pages like

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={Index} />
    <Route path="/create" component={Create} />
    <Route path="/view/:id" component={View} />
    <Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} />
  </Switch>
</Route>
```

All the routes work fine on this. My view page layout looks something like this.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NAVIGATION | HOME | ABOUT 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Side bar    |
|            |
|Option 1    |             Content that changes based on sidebar option
|Option 2    |
|            |
```

Here the navigation bar and the side bar will always remain the same but the content changes based on the option selected in the sidebar. To do so I made my view like

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col>
       <Sidebar />
    </Col>
    <Col>
       <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/option1" component={Option1} />
            <Route path="/option2" component={Option2} />
          </Switch>
       <Router>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

I assumed this would replace the content section with the Option components but it doesn't seem to work like that. Is there something I'm missing? I did try adding the routes to App.js which works fine but it won't load the `<Sidebar />` component. I guess I could load the sidebar in each view but that defeats the purpose of React. I'm very to new to React so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To access the route somewhere in your application:

1. Import `Link` (or `NavLink` if necessary) from `react-router-dom`.
2. Use it:

```js
<Link to="/create">Create</Link>
```

I've set up a working [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-frost-ukewv) for you which is doing what you want.dex.

Basic structure:

*index.js* — create `BrowserRouter wrapper

```js
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>,
```

*App.js* — Sets up basic structure.

```js
<div className="App">
  <Sidebar />
  <Main />
</div>
```

*Main.js* — Establish routing logic

```js
<main>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/create" component={Create} />
    <Route exact path="/destroy" component={Destroy} />
  </Switch>
</main>
```

*Sidebar.js* — Access the route

```js
<aside>
  <nav aria-label="main navigation">
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/create">Create</Link>
    <Link to="/destroy">Destroy</Link>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

[image]

Comment: This is basically how my sidebar is set up currently 
```<NavLink to="/option1">Option 1</NavLink>```

Comment: I have the same set up right now. The only difference I see is that all my components are class components does that make a difference?

Comment: @JustinS  That shouldn't matter. You must be missing something that is causing other components to re-render.

Comment: @JustinS I'm not sure how else to help. If you can post your work somewhere that I can fork and test, it would allow me to better help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help Andy. You were right about me re-rendering a component. Basically I was routing to my View from App.js and I was routing the same route again in my View as the landing page. I removed that its behaving the proper way. Really appreciate the help

Comment: I know its asking too much but I have another question about react that maybe you can provide some insight on. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60680118/how-to-handle-multiple-groups-of-radio-button-in-react?noredirect=1#comment107359349_60680118
I tried the first answer that was provided but haven't got much out of it

Comment: I thought you it worked but it apparently didn't and still cant figure out why

Comment: @JustinS You need to upload your code somewhere we can test it.